# How to fetch and post data with DRF and Jquery

Tags: jquery, django, api, django-rest-framework

I am very new to using API and JS so please go easy on me. I have done tons of trouble shooting but I can't seem to find any reliable information that I can personally comprehend.

I have all of my viewsets and serializers set up and the API works perfectly. I am trying to get it work on the front end now.

I am currently at the point where I can Post my cart to the database and it generates an ID, but the items aren't been added. I am not asking for anyone to do it all for me but any guidance would be very much appreciated, at the very least a decent guide to follow.

Here is my current **JS**:

```
const updateBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.update-cart');
const user = '{{request.user}}';

for(let i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent page from refreshing
        const productId = this.dataset.product;
        const action = this.dataset.action;
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'action:', action);

        console.log('USER:', user);
        createCart(productId, action); // Pass cartId to the function
    });
}

function createCart(productId, action){
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    console.log('User is logged in, sending data...');

    const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/carts/`;

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action}),
        mode: 'same-origin',
    })
    .then((response) =>{
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) =>{
        console.log('data:', data);
        const cartId = data.id;
        const cartIdUrl = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/carts/${cartId}/items/${productId}/`;
        
        fetch(cartIdUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'product': productId, 'quantity': 1}),
            mode: 'same-origin',
        })
        .then((response) =>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) =>{
            console.log('data:', data);
            console.log('cartId:', cartId);
            location.reload();
        });
    });
}
```

Here are my **Viewsets and Serializers relating to my API**

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = SimpleProductSerializer()
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_price(self, cart_item:CartItem):
        return cart_item.quantity * cart_item.product.price
    
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'product', 'quantity', 'total_price']

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    items = CartItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_total_price(self, cart):
        return sum([item.quantity * item.product.price for item in cart.items.all()])

    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ['id', 'items', 'total_price']
    
class AddCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def validate_product_id(self, value):
        if not Product.objects.filter(pk=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('No product with the given ID was found.')
        return value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        cart_id = self.context['cart_id']
        product_id = self.validated_data['product_id']
        quantity = self.validated_data['quantity']

        try: 
            cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(cart_id=cart_id, product_id=product_id)
            cart_item.quantity += quantity
            cart_item.save()
            self.instance = cart_item
        except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
            self.instance = CartItem.objects.create(cart_id=cart_id, **self.validated_data)
        
        return self.instance

    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['id', 'product_id', 'quantity']

class UpdateCartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ['quantity']

class CartViewSet(CreateModelMixin,
                  RetrieveModelMixin,
                  DestroyModelMixin,
                  GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Cart.objects.prefetch_related('items__product').all()
    serializer_class = CartSerializer

class CartItemViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'delete']
   
    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return AddCartItemSerializer
        elif self.request.method == 'PATCH':
            return UpdateCartItemSerializer
        return CartItemSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'cart_id': self.kwargs['cart_pk']}

    def get_queryset(self):
        return CartItem.objects \
                .filter(cart_id=self.kwargs['cart_pk']) \
                .select_related('product')
```